# Avoidance of double negation in early modern English? (Spenser's The Faerie Queene)

Tags: relative-clauses, early-modern-english, double-negation

There's this very famous line in Edmund Spenser's *The Faerie Queene* (Book V, Canto II, Stanza 39) that reads

> For there is nothing lost, that may be found, if sought.

I know that the interpretation is that nothing is ever really lost, it's all a matter of searching, etc., but I'm totally puzzled by the syntax: why isn't it

> For there is nothing lost, that may *not* be found, if sought.

No one is fond of a double negation, but a literal reading of the original verse seems to be "because there is not one thing that, once lost, may be found again." Are we before a peculiarity of early modern English? Of Spenser's? Or is it just me, as a non-native speaker, that wrongly feel something's out of place?

Comment: Perhaps it's the same as "Nothing that may be found is (truly) lost." There are whole books about negation in English though.

Comment: I think @StuartF Is right. It's an inverted form if "if it may be found, it's not really lost".

Comment: Thanks StuartF and Barmar!